# Fill chart data from API in angular using ngx-pie-charts

Tags: angular, angular7

i am newbie in angular , below is the code that consuming API and get data in (name,value) pairs to fill data in pie chart but chart is only showing single record, and i have X records, what i am doing wrong in below code.
Thank you in advance

```
  this.service.getsubordintesummary(30).subscribe(res=>
   {
            this.subordinatesummary=res as subordinatesummary[]; 
       for(i=0;i<=this.subordinatesummary.length;i++)
         {
           this.widget7.device=
        [
           {
             name:this.subordinatesummary[0].subordinates[i].Description,
             value:this.subordinatesummary[0].subordinates[i].EmpCount,
           }
       ]
    }
  }


 })
```

JSON DATA:

```
[
  {
   "total":10,
     "subordinates":
       [
         {"Description":"IT sector","Ecount":1},
         {"Description":"MWS sector","Ecount":3}
       ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you add the json data

Comment: Can you disclose your chart code.

Comment: i have added the json data @AkhilAravind

Comment: @SaisivaA my chart code is very simple , its not necessary because the issue is in typescript code

Comment: what chart are you using

Comment: ngx-charts-pie-chart angular 7

Comment: https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/pie-chart

Comment: @FullStackLoser did the below solution solved your problem ??

Comment: @AkhilAravind i have tried the below code but still it doesn't solved the problem , chart is not showing any data.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle and implemented likewise ??

Comment: yes i have checked the fiddle , Actually if i give static data like you refer in fiddle, it works perfectly, the problem occurs when data is iterated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data from the api response is like

```
this.data:any[]=[
  {
   "total":10,
     "subordinates":
       [
         {"Description":"IT sector","Ecount":1},
         {"Description":"MWS sector","Ecount":3}
       ]
  },
  {
   "total":11,
     "subordinates":
       [
         {"Description":"IT development","Ecount":5},
         {"Description":"Service","Ecount":8}
       ]
  }
]
```

You need to implement the iteration function as

```
let chartData: any[]=[];
this.data.map(subordinate => subordinate.subordinates.map(item => {
  chartData.push({name: item.Description, value: item.Ecount})
  })
)
```

Here `chartData` contains the pireChart data type.That is like

```
{
    "name": "Germany",
    "value": 8940000
  },
  {
    "name": "USA",
    "value": 5000000
  },
```

Since  chart only accepts this data format.

Check the fiddle for complete solution. Also let me know if you need any more explanation.

[Check the fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-pie-chart)